# Remove ember-cli-mirage from ember

Tags: ember-cli-mirage, ember-cli-rails

I am using ember-cli-mirage to serve for requests. As I have my rails api to serve those request, how i shd remove or uninstall ember-cli-mirage from my ember ?

If am removing mirage folder, am getting build error !!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should leave Mirage installed (and the folder on disk) but *disable* the server whenever you want to use your actual backend API. This will let you use Mirage in selective environments, for example in testing.

By default, Mirage is disabled in `production`, and also in `development` when using the `-proxy` option.

To disable Mirage explicitly, you can set the [enabled config option](http://www.ember-cli-mirage.com/docs/v0.2.x/configuration/#enabled) to `false`. For example, to always disable in development:

```
// config/environment.js
...
if (environment === 'development') {
  ENV['ember-cli-mirage'] = {
    enabled: false
  };
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Leave mirage installed, if you want to use your backend api just launch ember with

```
    ember s --proxy http://localhost:8000
```

if api's are running on your machine on port 8000.

More info on mirage official site: http://www.ember-cli-mirage.com/docs/v0.3.x/configuration/#enabled